# How can I pace my walking sound in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, game-development

I tried to add a walking sound to my unity character when the movement input is detected, it works, however, the sound is triggering too rapidly and I'd like to pace it out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WalkingSound : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Update() {

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ) {
            
            audioSource.enabled = true;
        } else {
            audioSource.enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to use an enumerator with a time delay the audio doesn't play at all, but it does with the basic script above. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a timer count down on playing or play it only in time with the foot position of an animation or.....

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

Using animation event is a good solution to your problem but if you are not using any sort of animation ,u can just use coroutine and play the sound with some delay.
example:

```
private  playSoundCoroutine;

private void Update ()
{

  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)){

      if (playSoundCoroutine == null)
         playSoundCoroutine = StartCoroutine (PlayWalkSound (delayDuration));
    
  }
  else{

      playSoundCoroutine == null;
      audioSource.enabled = false;
    }
}



private IEnumerator PlayWalkSound (float delay)
{
  //or use WaitUntil 
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);
  PlaySound ();
  playSoundCoroutine = null;
}
```

> above example code worked for me,i called this whenever player made
> some movement and remember to set delay as per your preference and it
> might need to be changed for also inAirMovement or sprint

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck **Loop Checkbox** on AudioSource and add a **Animation Event** to your Walking animation to play AudioSource